ggplot2 geom_smooth lm : add device error band (not CI, not standard error)?
given a confidence interval plotted by geom_smooth lm, is there a way to wrap the CI in an error band illustrating the accuracy spec associated with the device generating the plotted data?
(or would that be an enhancement request for geom_smooth()? )


Would it be enough to do a linear fit outside of ggplot, build a data frame with the predicted values and the +/- 3% values, and use that to plot your rectangle?

Calculate the error outside of ggplot, then use geom_ribbon() with aes(ymin = y - error, ymax = y + error).  That way you also get correct vertical ends instead of 90 degree angles.

Ideally, the device accuracy "error band" gets wrapped around the calculated confidence interval (so its not a pair of straight lines, and its not a rectangle, that's an artifact of my attempted illustration). Thank you for the geom_ribbon() suggestion. A linear fit outside of ggplot sort of defeats the purpose.

@FJCC put down "enhancement request" and I'll accept that as the solution. Thank you.
